# Finding $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim _{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=0 $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm having trouble understanding limits at infinity. For instance,

> If $$\lim _{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=0 $$
> where $a$ and $b$ are some real constants; find $a$ and $b$.

As per the solution the value of $a$ must be $1$ and the value of b is $-1$. Why?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1}=x-1+\dfrac2{x+1}$

Comment: Read this before you post your next question: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b&=\frac{x^2+1-ax(x+1)-b(x+1)}{x+1}\\&=\frac{x^2(1-a)+x(-a-b)+(1-b)}{x+1}.\end{align}

Therefore

$$\lim _{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{x^2(1-a)+x(-a-b)+(1-b)}{x+1}\right)=0,$$

only if the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator. In order for this to happen, $a$ must be equal to $1$ so that the $x^2$ term in the numerator is $0$. Then, the $x$ term in the numerator must also be $0$ and we find:

$$-a-b=0 \implies -1-b=0 \implies b=-1.$$

Comment: This concept has not been taught to me yet. As of now, i was asked to memorize that if the the degree of numerator is less than that of the denominator, the value of a given limit will be equal to zero. In which chapter does this concept come under?

Comment: Suppose your limit is in the form: $$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{P(x)\over Q(x)}$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are functions of the form $\sum x^k \,\,\,,k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then, whichever of $P$ and $Q$ has the term with highest degree 'wins'. If $P$ has the term with highest degree, then $L=\infty$, and if $Q$ has the term with highest degree, then $L=0$. If $P$ and $Q$ have the same term with highest degree, then you can just take the coefficients of the largest powers as the limit (unless $P=Q=0$, in which case the limit is undefined).

Comment: I'm not sure which textbook you are using. An online summary of limits at infinity is shown [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/limits-infinity.html).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=\frac{x^2+1+2x-2x}{x+1}$$

$$=\frac{(x+1)^2-2x}{x+1}=x+1-\frac{2x}{x+1}$$

thus

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b=(1-a)x+1-b-\frac{2x}{x+1}$$

If $ a\ne 1$, the limit will be infinite.Then necessariliy, $ a=1$.

in this case, the limit is
$$1-b-2=0$$
So, $ b=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x(x+1)}=1,$$ which gives $a=1$.

Now, $$b=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}-x\right).$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1}=x-1+\dfrac2{x+1}$,

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{x+1}-ax-b\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(x-1+\dfrac2{x+1}-ax-b\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left((1-a)x-(1+b)+\dfrac2{x+1}\right)=0$ when $1-a=1+b=0.$